# Find a string in command line argument?

Tags: c

I am currently working on a program in C that can take in command line arguments and manipulate them in various ways. In this particular segment I want to read through each argument passed and check if the word "Candy" appears in any possible way. So far this is what I have...

```
// To test if "Candy" appears in the argument
if (strcmp(argv[i], "Candy", 5) == 0)
{
    printf("Candy!\n", argv[i+1]);
}
```

My question is am I using `strcmp` statement correctly? I have looked for this problem on here, but I can't seem to find any examples in C specifically. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: `strcmp()` doesn't take a 3rd (length) parameter only `strncmp()` does. Also it's only going to work if the word starts with Candy not if it's inside of the word. Finally `strstr()` is a better option.

Comment: man strcmp can be very helpful. Either at linux prompt or directly into google

Comment: strstr will search for a string anywhere in a given string

Comment: The fact that it does not compile should be a pretty good indication that you're using it wrong...

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by *"appears in any possible way"*, but a simple way to check for any possible `"Candy"` is to make a copy of the argument, convert it to lower case, and then  search with `strstr` for `"candy"`. That will find any case-combination of `"candy"` anywhere within an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely on the right track!

But notice: The prototype of the function strcmp is

`int strcmp(const char *str1, const char *str2)`

--> it only takes two arguments, not three!

if you want to test if an argument is "Candy", the correct approach would be:

```
// To test if "Candy" appears in the argument
if (strcmp(argv[i], "Candy") == 0)
{
    printf("Candy!\n");
    // printf("Candy!\n", argv[i+1]); <- why the argv[i+1] in the original question?? too many arguments for printf...
}
```

By the way, what compiler are you using? From the looks of it, you should have been getting all kinds of errors and warnings!

---

Alternatively, if you want to find if an argument contains the word Candy, as in SugarCandy or SmellyCandyIsBad, you should strstr() instead of strcmp(). Quoting,

> Description
>
> The C library function char `*strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)` function finds the first occurrence of the substring needle in the string haystack. The terminating '\0' characters are not compared.
>
> Declaration
>
> Following is the declaration for strstr() function.
>
> `char *strstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)`

This implies that to test if the letters "Candy" appear in an argument string, one must do the following:

```
// To test if "Candy" appears in the argument in any form
if (strstr(argv[i], "Candy")) // strstr != 0
{
    printf("Candy!\n");
}
```

Comment: `if (strcmp(argv[i], "Candy") == 0)` <-- This does not test if "Candy" appears in the argument. It tests if the argument is exactly "Candy". For example, "Candycane" will fail the test, which isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: oh my bad. it seemed like that's what he was aiming for-- he was a bit vague. I'll leave my answer either ways

Comment: You can edit your answer to correct it, and I recommend that you do before somebody downvotes it.

Comment: Ok, good idea. I've edited the answer to include a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

> *My question is am I using strcmp statement correctly?*

No your are not, `strcmp` takes only two arguments. `strncmp`<sup>1</sup> however takes a third argument which is the maximal length to be compared.

```
if ( strncmp( argv[i], "Candy", 5)==0)
    ...
```

would be correct though.

Also your the `printf` is kind of wrong, though.

You are passing an argument, but your format doesn't have the `%s` conversion specifier, so the argument `argv[i+1]` is simply ignored and not printed.

Be careful with `argv[i+1]`, though. If `i` is equal to `argc-1`, meaning it's the last argument, `argv[i+1]` is `NULL` and doing this

```
printf("something %s\n", NULL);
```

is undefined behaviour.

---

**Footnotes**

<sup>1</sup>Quote from the man page:

> *man strcmp*
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
>
> int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> int strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `strcmp()` function compares the two strings `s1` and `s2`.
>   It returns an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if `s1` is
>   found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than `s2`.
>
> The `strncmp()` function is similar, **except it compares only the first (at most) `n` bytes** of `s1` and `s2`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your feedback. After further evaluation, I realized it would be better to use "strstr".

Here is my entire code so far...

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *str = argv[1];
    int j;
    int i = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);

    if(argc>=2) // If the more than just filenam is argumented, will continue.
    {   
        for (i=0;i<argc;i++) // Loops through each argument.
        {
            for(i=0,j=len-1;i<j;i++,j--) //Loop for swapping characters.
            {
                char c = str[i];
                str[i] = str[j];
                str[j] =c;

                if(strstr(str, "candy") !=NULL)
                    {
                    printf("%scandy!\n", argv[i+1]);
                    }
                else
                    {
                    printf("%s\n", argv[i+1]);
                    }

            }
        }


    }
    else //(argc < 2) // If not enough arguments passed in the command line I will die!!!
        {
        exit(1);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Again, thank you to everyone that posted. I think I have it pretty close to working fully :D. As of now when I run it, it gives me the first word backwards. As of now it prints the word backwards, but its hit or miss and can give it out of order. Any idea on how to fix that? I know that I have the argv[i+1] but I just do not want to print the initial filename or ./a.out.

Comment: To discard the initial filename you could increment the argv pointer such that it points to the second argument. So put `argv++;` at the beginning of main and then use `argv[i]` to access the first argument. If that's what you want. Also, I recommend you learn pointers as soon as possible if you want to be successful in C